# Renaming countries in list

Tags: python

I have a text file that is formatted as such, with the movie name, rating score and country of origin all separated by tab space on each line:

```
"3:0 f¸r die B‰rte" (1971)  6.8 West Germany
"3K Check In" (2002)    4.3 Federal Republic of Yugoslavia
"3MW: Rivers of Blood" (2008)   7.9 UK
"3Way" (2008)   8.2 USA
"3rd Rock from the Sun" (1996)  7.8 USA
"3rd and Bird" (2008)   7.8 UK
"3satfestival" (2000)   6.7 Germany
```

My goal is to calculate the average rating score for each country, which works with the code I have below. However, I also want to rename some of the countries, such as 'West Germany' to 'Germany' so that their rating scores can be added together, but the code I have doesn't work ie. the rating scores for 'West Germany' and 'Germany' are still calculated separately. What changes can I make?

```
import collections

MovieRating = collections.namedtuple('MovieRating', ['countryorigin', 'ratingscore'])

ratings = {}

movie = open("movieRatingscore.txt", "r") #open the country rating data file

for line in movie.readlines():
    line.rstrip()
    (moviename, ratingscore, countryorigin) = line.split('\t')
    if countryorigin == 'West Germany':
        countryorigin = 'Germany'
    ratingscore = float(ratingscore)
    if countryorigin in ratings:
        ratings[countryorigin].append(ratingscore)
    else:
        ratings[countryorigin] = [ratingscore]

average = lambda alist: sum(alist)/len(alist)
average_ratings = [MovieRating(countryorigin, average(ratings[countryorigin])) for countryorigin in ratings]

print "\nCountries with the highest average movie rating\n------------------------------"
sorted_ratings = sorted(average_ratings, key=lambda countryorigin: countryorigin.ratingscore, reverse=True)
for i, j in enumerate(sorted_ratings):
    print '%i. %s \t%g' % (i + 1, j.countryorigin, j.ratingscore)
```

Comment: Are you sure your file is properly separated with tabs?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the original data?  I suspect the formatting of your text file is not what you think it is, e.g.:  there might be several whitespaces separating words such as `\t` followed by a space.

Comment: Couldn't you just do a find and replace all to rename the countries with a text editor?

Comment: @user3440320, It's not that I don't trust you, but it's impossible for us to be helpful without the actual data.  Could you kindly post it for us?

Comment: I don't have link to the original data. I created the text file by merging 2 different lists and checked that every line is properly separated by \t. If I do `(moviename, ratingscore, countryorigin) = line.split('\t')` followed by `print countryorigin`, python returns the countries correctly.

Comment: @user3440320, In that case, please use a pastebin service such as `paste.ubuntu.com` and provide us with the link.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use a dictionary to replace the words. Check the sample code:

```
dt = {'West Germany': 'Germany', 'another': 'Replaced'}
for line in movie.readlines():
    for item in dt:
        line = line.replace(item, dt[item])
```

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, any text comparison should be done between stripped and lowered strings.  This avoids getting tripped up by files that use multiple whitespace separators.

Also, a more generalizable check for transforming `West Germany` into `Germany` would be to check if the substring `germany` is contained in the string.  Thus:

```
for line in map(str.strip, movie.readlines()):
    (moviename, ratingscore, countryorigin) = map(str.strip, line.split('\t'))
    if "germany" in countryorigin.lower():
        countryorigin = 'Germany'
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The format of your file is incorrect (you have spaces where you want tabs), after making the file into a string list with tab literals as such:

```
movie =["\"3:0 f¸r die B‰rte\" (1971)\t6.8\tWest Germany",
"\"3K Check In\" (2002)\t4.3\tFederal Republic of Yugoslavia",
"\"3MW: Rivers of Blood\" (2008)\t7.9\tUK",
"\"3Way\" (2008)\t8.2\tUSA",
"\"3rd Rock from the Sun\" (1996)\t7.8\tUSA",
"\"3rd and Bird\" (2008)\t7.8\tUK",
"\"3satfestival\" (2000)\t6.7\tGermany"]

for line in movie:
  ....
```

I get the output:

```
Countries with the highest average movie rating
------------------------------
1. USA  8
2. UK   7.85
3. Germany  6.75
4. Federal Republic of Yugoslavia   4.3
```

Comment: @user3440320, No, you should provide us with the file so that we can actually know if it's a format problem.  Until then, this answer strikes me as speculative, and I suspect this is why it was downvoted.

Comment: yes your code is fine (although you should think of a better way to replace countries). Use an editor that shows you whitespaces literally, @blz, I have no idea why there was a downvote, I tested the code (except for the file bit) unchanged and got the result OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Using the expression

```
print repr(countryorigin)
```

should show you the issue. The string is "West Germany\n" rather than "West Germany", which is why the equality check is failing. From the python docs:

**str.rstrip([chars])** Return a copy of the string with trailing characters removed.

You are performing the strip command but it's not being saved back to line. You can fix the issue by adding line = line.rstrip(), but I think @blz has the best syntax:

```
for line in map(str.strip, movie.readlines()):
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you describe does seem to come from your csv file. Your code seems just fine, logic-wise.

But you should use the tools provided by the [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/index.html), they can do much of the heavy lifting for you.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple
from operator import attrgetter, itemgetter
from itertools import imap

MovieRating = namedtuple('MovieRating', 'countryorigin ratingscore')

fieldnames = 'name', 'year', 'score', 'country'
score_and_country = itemgetter('score', 'country')
ratings = defaultdict(list)

with open("movieRatingscore.txt", "r") as moviefile:
    movies = csv.DictReader(moviefile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter='\t')
    for score, country in imap(score_and_country, movies):
        if country == 'West Germany':
            country = 'Germany'
        ratings[country].append(float(score))

average = lambda alist: sum(alist) / len(alist)
average_ratings = [MovieRating(country, average(scores))
                   for country, scores in ratings.iteritems()]

print
print "Countries with the highest average movie rating"
print "------------------------------"
sorted_ratings = sorted(average_ratings, key=attrgetter('ratingscore'),
                        reverse=True)
for i, j in enumerate(sorted_ratings):
    print '%i. %s \t%g' % (i + 1, j.countryorigin, j.ratingscore)
```